# Redux | Why this Redux's state parameter is not being updated?

Tags: javascript, redux

I'm trying to increase the number of articles in a list from a Redux's state. The item's quantity parameter is not being updated, it only goes from 1 to 2, but nothing more. I've read about the Redux's state immutability so I cloned the state but I think that I'm not updating the Redux's state properly. When the `increaseitem()` function is executed, it increases the number of items from 1 to 2, no matter how many times I execute this function.

This is the reducer:

```
import {INCREASEITEM} from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {basket: [] };

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case INCREASEITEM:
   
   //Cloning the list of items
      let newBasket = [...state.basket];
      
        // Getting the item's index in the basket array
      let index = newBasket.findIndex( element => {
        if (element.itemCode === '0A3BC') { //0A3BC is a dummy code
          return true;
        }})

        //Cloning the object
        let itemUpdated = {...newBasket[index]}; // {code:'0A3BC' , qty: 1}

        // Incrase in 1 the product quantity 
        itemUpdated.itemQty = itemUpdated.itemQty +1; // {code:'0A3BC' , qty: 2}

        // update the cloned basket
      newBasket.splice(index, 0, itemUpdated)
          

      return { 
        ...state,
        initialState:{
          ...state.initialState,
          basket: newBasket
        }
        
        };

 ...
```

}

I've defined a default state:

```
const initialState = {basket: [{itemCode: '4S4C', itemQty: 1},{itemCode: '0A3BC', itemQty: 2},] };
```

When I execute the increaseitem() function, it returns:

```
(3) […]
​
0: Object { itemCode: "4S4C", itemQty: 1 }
​
1: Object { itemCode: "0A3BC", itemQty: 3 }
​
2: Object { itemCode: "0A3BC", itemQty: 2 }
​
length: 3
​
<prototype>: []
```

Comment: check by changing to ```let newBasket = [...state.initialState.basket]```

Comment: This would copy the original state, `basket: {}` not the last state, wouldn't it? I tried, but this error occurs `TypeError: state.initialState is undefined`

Comment: First, define a default case and return the state from it, this case handle if this reducer does not care about incoming action type.

Also, new basket should be coming from action.payload I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In accord with the Redux's documentation and comments, I solved this problem by parsing the new item's quantity to the reducer and then replacing the actual item's quantity.

**Reducer**

```
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {

    case INCREASEITEM:
      
//The basket is clooned
      let newBasket = [...state.basket]; 

//Getting the item's index in the basket that needs to be updated

      let indexItemToUpdate = newBasket.findIndex( element => {
        if (element.itemCode === action.itemCode) {
          return true;
        }})

  //This console logs were used to verify the update process
      console.log('Actual number of items', newBasket[indexItemToUpdate].itemQty);
      console.log('New number of items', action.itemQty)
//Updating the parameter
      newBasket[indexItemToUpdate].itemQty = action.itemQty
//Verifying the item has been updated
      console.log('updated item', newBasket[indexItemToUpdate].itemQty)
//Verifying the basket has been updated
      console.log('updated basket', newBasket)
      return { 
        ...state,
          ...{
            baseket:newBasket //Updating the state         
      }};
        
  default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the context of your reducer the state is {basket: [] }. I believe initialState is an irrelevant extra variable.

You could try this:

```
export default function reducer(state = {basket: [] }, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

        case INCREASEITEM:

            //Cloning the list of items
            let newBasket = [...state.basket];

            // Getting the item's index in the basket array
            let index = newBasket.findIndex(element => {
                if (element.itemCode === '0A3BC') { //0A3BC is a dummy code
                    return true;
                }
            })

            //Cloning the object
            let itemUpdated = {...newBasket[index]}; // {code:'0A3BC' , qty: 1}

            // Incrase in 1 the product quantity
            itemUpdated.itemQty = itemUpdated.itemQty + 1; // {code:'0A3BC' , qty: 2}

            // update the cloned basket
            newBasket.splice(index, 0, itemUpdated)


            return {...state, ...{basket: newBasket}}
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

You should also include a default that returns an unmodified state.

Comment: I've tried this but got the same result: the number of items only reaches to 2.